# Which .NET controls don't use javascript to handle events?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, event-handling, onclick, dopostback

I noticed that the

```
asp:Button
```

for example will work without javascript enabled in the browser.  However any other control with an "OnClick" or "OnServerClick" event must use the javascript_doPostback.

Are there any controls besides the Button that don't need to use javascript?

I want to know because I want to be able to style the Control however I want without it looking like a button, and I want it to still work without the user having javascript enabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you want the control to look like, someone might have some alternate suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is none.  The button submits the form (as buttons will do) but no other controls auto-submit a form without a client side event handler.

Note that this also applies to the Link button.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up--just in case anyone has anyother ideas, I will describe: I want the control to appear simply as a text with a hover style.

Answer (score 3):

_doPostback is the heart of ASP.NET. If you don't want to require the use of Javascript then ASP.NET isn't the language for you.